# Bootstrap Confirmation: Detect open and close states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, confirmation

I am trying to detect when the bootstrap confirmation is opened and closed but I am having no luck with detecting this. I am using an `<a>` tag to trigger the confirmation (code down below), and trying to detect this is jquery.

```
<a class="delete" data-toggle="confirmation" title="" data-original-title="Delete Row?">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

I originally tried to detect the button click but failed in doing so. It would be better if the confirmation is able to trigger a function once opened and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding my answer thanks to the other answers getting me there. The code simply looks at the trigger button which in my case has a class name of **delete** and then looks for a `<div>` with the class name **popover** to see if it is visible or not.

```
if ($(".delete").next('div.popover:visible').length){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may you "data-on-confirm" and "data-on-cancel" attributes to register your callbacks for those particular events.These are given in the documentation provided by the bootstrap confirmation plugin.

Eg
`<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-on-confirm="myAcceptFunction" data-on-cancel="myRejectFunction">Confirmation 1</button>`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it led me to finding what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use events, e.g.:

```
var modalIsShown = false;

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    modalIsShown = true;
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    modalIsShown = false;
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it led me to finding what I needed.